# Discord.py moderation event

Tags: python, events, discord, discord.py, bots

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('Some bad word'):
        guild = ctx.guild
        await message.channel.send(f'%s, ou, you said bad word. I have to mute you for 1 hour.')
        mutedRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Muted')
        await member.add_role(mutedRole)
        await asyncio.sleep(3600)
        await member.remove_roles(mutedRole)
```

Hi everyone! I cant create an event, who mute a member, who wrote a bad word in a chat, because **on_message** does not accept arguments **member**, **ctx** etc. What shall i do, to create this "Moderation" event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at the docs, `message` does have everything you need. You can replace `ctx.guild` with `message.guild` and `member` with `message.author`.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message

```py
guild = message.guild
await message.channel.send(f'%s, ou, you said bad word. I have to mute you for 1 hour.')
mutedRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Muted')
await message.author.add_role(mutedRole)
await asyncio.sleep(3600)
await message.author.remove_roles(mutedRole)
```